# Rails 3.1.1 asset pipeline Heroku caching gotcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

The problem in a nutshell is that in development mode we'd make changes to CSS or JS files but would always get cached/old versions of these files. Nothing I did had any effect. I checked configuration dozens of times and tried every combination of config values but always kept getting the same results: stale/cached files. I had to actually run in production mode and restart the server after every change to test.

I spent days tearing my hair out over this issue, looked at dozens of stackoverflow questions on the asset pipeline but never found one that addressed it so I thought I'd post it here for posterity.

We use Heroku and precompile our assets because Heroku fails to precompile for us (we also use devise which apparently is the cause of the heroku precompilation failure). So in order to push our precompiled assets up to Heroku we have to check them in to git.

**Here's the problem**.

When we upgraded to **Rails 3.1.1** asset precompilation produced files both with and without the MD5 hash in the name. I didn't think much of this and went ahead and checked all these files in so I could push to heroku. Sometime later I noticed the problem with cached results in development mode. The precompiled and checked in assets without the MD5 hashes were being served from /public/assets as static files which prevented us from seeing any changes we were making in /app/assets.

After finally realizing this I ran git rm /public/assets and everything works again. So the takeaway is: **Be careful checking assets into git!**

To turn this into a question: how do others do this? Am I missing something obvious? What I'd really like is for Heroku to precompile my assets for me but it is failing with a db connection error that I gather is because of devise. I had hoped Rails 3.1.1 fixed this but it didn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you checked out this [devise issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1339) on github? Specifically Jose Valim says

> Rails 3.1.1 final has a method called
>   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile. If you set it to false, you
>   should be good but it won't allow you to access model information on
>   your assets (which you probably shouldn't anyway).

Maybe this will allow the precompile to happen on Heroku for you.

Comment: Dty, I had tried this exact configuration before posting this question but it didn't work for me at the time. However, I just tried it again, this time with Devise 1.4.9 and lo and behold it works! Thanks for the suggestion which made me try this again.

Comment: @JeffCutler-Stamm glad it worked out! I'm also hosting a rails 3.1.1 app on heroku but haven't added devise yet (but will soon)

Comment: I would note that you add that to config/application.rb

Comment: Actually, there is another way of making precompilation work on Heroku: They recently added a flag which makes the environment (so also the db) accessible during precompilation. Just ask them to switch it on. Worked fine for me! DB dependencies are not an issue anymore. Didn't know of that new flag config.assets.initialize_on_precompile though, will also try that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the asset precompilation does not work could well be, that the Heroku ENV vars are not present on slug compilation (deploy) as stated here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

There is an (experimental) way to enable the ENV vars during deploy for exactly this reason, find information here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this guide](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) from Heroku. It outlines the 3 ways to deploy Rails 3.1 apps. Two of these do not required local precompilation.

Comment: Thanks - but none of those work for me. As I mentioned in the question, I think this is due to devise. Precompilation during slug compilation always fails with a database connection error.

Comment: you're saying run time compilation fails for you?

Comment: yes, runtime compilation fails so i'm stuck w/ precompilation before pushing to heroku.