# Is it a good/bad idea to include precompiled assets in git repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

Heroku docs [says](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#the-asset-pipeline) I can precompile assets locally and add them to git repo.

Personally I think there is many disadvantages having assets in repo. What do you think?

Comment: I agree that assets should be left out of the repo, particularly if your asset pipeline is small enough to push into Heroku for compiling. Otherwise, a external asset host like S3 might work. This discussion was helpful to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963049/heroku-rails-3-1-app-compiling-assets-locally-vs-compiling-assets-during-slug

Comment: If you think the link was helpful, you might want to vote it up so that others know. I didn't want to create a separate answer since it's just referring to another answer.